# PHP to execute Python scripts for GPIO

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, php, webiopi

I found this code somewhere, that can execute Python scripts from PHP.

I've installed apache2 on the Pi and I'm able to access the PHP script. But when I press the HTML buttons, nothing happens! :(

When I execute the python script via SSH, it works.. so theres nothing wrong with the python scripts I think.

I'm using WebIOPi to monitor the status of the GPIO pins.

Whats the mistake?

PS: I know that this may not be a very safe approach to control the GPIO. I just wanna give it a try though :)

TIA.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['RedON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/red_on.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['RedOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/red_off.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['YellowON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/yellow_on.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['YellowOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/yellow_off.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['GreenON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/green_on.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['GreenOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/green_off.py');
}
?>

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <table
 style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
 border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Turn LED on</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Turn LED off</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RedON">Red On</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RedOFF">Red Off</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="YellowON">Yellow On</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="YellowOFF">Yellow Off</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="GreenON">Green On</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="GreenOFF">Green Off</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that this is a permission issue. Any suggestions to resolve the same is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `sudo python XYZ` will be execute as the apache user. You'll need to add this user to your sudoers file.

```bash
sudo echo "apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Replace "apache" with your systems apache username (may be "www-data", "httpd" or "www" on some systems.)

**Suggestion**

Why use Apache or PHP at all? [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) is extremely simple to set-up. You can have this server handle your python scripts, while running with super-user privileges.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. The username was www-data in my case. :)
And yeah, Apache2 is heavy! Thanks for the suggestion too.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo python /var/www/red_on.py` most probably asks for a sudo password, which is not provided anywhere, and the command fails.

you may try `echo <password> | sudo -S ...`, however I haven't checked if output redirect works well in the PHP `exec()`.

Comment: This will work. From `man` pages, you'll need to run `sudo` with this `-S` switch to read password from `stdin`. `echo <password> | sudo -S ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commands

```
chown root:root ./script
chmod 4775 ./script
```