# Security issues in PHP executing PYTHON scrips

Tags: rpi.gpio, security, apache-httpd

So I've got a PHP script thats capable of executing Python commands (to control GPIO), thanks to the users of StackExchange. My previous question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/php-to-execute-python-scripts-for-gpio).

Now I'm able to control the GPIO pins from a script hosted in Apache2 of the Pi. This was done by adding the user www-data to the sudoers file. I'm planning to PORT-FORWARD my router so that I can control my Pi through the internet.

Although I hear everywhere that this approach is not recommended, I am unclear about the possible security issues in doing the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cross site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) could allow someone to become root by tricking your server into running a command possibly destroying your Pi. Instead you should make a group with

```
 addgroup gpio
```

then give access to GPIO pins

```
 chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/gpio
```

then add www-data to gpio group

```
 adduser www-data gpio
```

Finally, *remove www-data from sudoers!*