# Securing GPIO groups vs gpio-admin

Tags: gpio

The project I am working on right now requires a webserver and some server side code to access the gpio pins.  I know that the pins require root access and I need to secure them before I open it up to the internet, but I'm not sure of the route to take to do so.

I have see some people use ***gpio-admin*** to do this, however, I also saw in another [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/security-issues-in-php-executing-python-scrips) that the pins can be secured by adding a group and changing a few rights.

Does gpio-admin do basically the same thing or is there more too it?  Would it be easier and just as secure to change the access to the pins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complication here is *how* you are using the pins.  If you use a library that uses `mmap()`, neither method here will work for you.   I do not know which libraries *do not* do this -- most of them do.  However, you only need to use such a library if you want the web server to be able to set the pull up/down resistors or one of the pi-specific modes.  If all you need to do is check/set the state (high/low) or direction (in/out) you can use the `/sys/class/gpio` interface directly (i.e., no library), and both these methods will work.

> Does gpio-admin do basically the same thing or is there more too it?

It does something pretty similar only on a pin by pin basis; you'll notice it also requires you create a `gpio` group and add users to it.

One thing it does which is not possible the other way is allow non-privileged users to manipulate the pull up/down resistors (but you must use `gpio-admin` to do so); this is done by setting the the [setuid bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on the executable.  There is a potential security risk in that it means the program actually runs as root, *regardless of who executes it.*   There is a necessity for such binaries on the system (e.g., `passwd`), but you must take care to ensure that the executable itself is not *writable* by anyone except root, otherwise they can replace/alter it and use it to do whatever they want.  The `make install` should do that (which you should run as root or via sudo).

> I'm not sure of the route to take

Probably the safest/most paranoid way to allow for this is to export the individual pins and make them owned by the server user, e.g.:

```
export 26 > /sys/class/gpio/export
chown -R httpd /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio26
```

You need to use the `devices/virtual` path in the second command instead of `class/gpio` because `chmod` (fortunately) will not follow symlinks.  The `httpd` username is just an example.

That needs to be done root; `/etc/rc.local`, if your system has one, is a good place to do this (it will be done at boot by init).

Again, this will only work for manipulating the GPIOs via that interface (which doesn't include stuff like setting the pull up/down resistors).  If you need to do something requiring one of the pi-specialized libraries, you will have to use a setuid binary in the manner of `gpio-admin`.

Comment: Looking over the `gpio-admin` source file it seems that, like you said, it simply access the `/sys/class/gpio`, changes the ownership and then exports or unexports the pin.  I'm hoping to create a website so I can check the status of my garage door - and various other things around the house.  I simply want to make it as secure as possible for a n00 guy and try to understand what I'm installing instead of blindly running something.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might have a look at joan's daemon.  That is a good idea.  Presumably it can be configured to restrict access in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of solutions.

I will tout my own which uses my pigpio library as the back end.

See pigpio CGI at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_code

The pigpio daemon runs as root and controls the gpios.

The web server software runs at an ordinary privilege.